# Use keyboard TAB to access downloads in the IE download window

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, keyboard

When I download a file, via some link/button on a webpage, the IE download window turns up (see picture, it's Dutch).
With the keyboard TAB key you can tab through the files on the window. But for each file there are buttons to Open or Save the file. How can I access these buttons via the keyboard ?

[image: IE download window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the **Tab** key, **Arrow** Keys and the **Enter** Keys. More details information, please refer to the following steps:

1. Use **`Ctrl + J`** to open the IE Download views
2. Use **`Tab`** key to select the download file
3. Use the **left arrow** (back arrow)and the **right arrow** (forward arrow) to select the option in the horizontal direction. To the Dropdown options, we could use the **up arrow** and **down arrow** to select item (The selected items will have a dashed border).
4. Click the **Enter** key to open the file.

[Note] After clicking the **Enter** key, there might be have some security prompt, you could also the **Tab** key and **Enter** Key to Click the related button.

The screenshot as below:

[image]